# What's more restrictive, the RPL or the AGPL?

Tags: licensing

What's the difference between the RPL licence and the AGPL licence?

Which one is more restrictive?

Answer (score 4):

The [`Reciprocal Public License`](http://opensource.org/licenses/rpl1.5.txt) requires any changes to be released (publically!) even when software is used only internally, the [`GNU Affero General Public License`](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl.html) does not.

The AGPL is also GPL-compatible, while the RPL is not.

These are the core differences.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; I guess this means that RPL is more restrictive than AGPL? And if yes, how about the web-service restriction that AGPL has? I wonder if an equivalent "ARPL" should exist.

Comment: @knocte I think it'd be better to discuss which is more 'free' as both are permissive licenses. Neither one really imposes restrictions, but they both give you some obligations. As to an "ARPL"... no, I think there are enough licenses around.

Comment: Yeah I don't mind, let me rephrase: which one imposes more obligations?

Comment: And I don't think "there are no enough licenses around" is a good argument. Does ARPL make sense or not and why?